# Implementation of split_binary function of Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm new in the Erlang world. I'm trying to implement the function split_binary. The function takes as input (list, index) and it splits the list in two lists according to the index.

```
split(Lst, N) when N>=list:lenght(Lst) -> Lst;
split(Lst, N) when N<list:lenght(Lst) -> splitHelper(list:reverse(Lst), 0, N, []).

splitHelper([H|T], X, N, Acc) ->
  if
    X>=N ->
      (list:reverse([H|T]), list:reverse(Acc));
    X<N ->
      splitHelper(T, X+1, N, [H|Acc])
  end.
```

How can I improve my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm new in the Erlang world. I'm trying to implement the function
> split_binary. The function takes as input (list, index) and it splits
> the list in two lists according to the index.

According to the erlang docs for [split_binary/2](https://erldocs.com/21.0/erts/erlang.html?i=0&search=split_bi#split_binary/2), the two arguments are a `binary`, which is not a list, and the number of `bytes` where you want to split the binary.

First, you need to have a basic understanding of what a binary is.  A binary is a sequence of bytes, where each byte is 8 bits representing some integer, e.g.

`0010 0001`

which is `33`. Here is an example of a binary:

```
<<1, 2, 3>>
```

When you don't specify a size for each integer, by default each integer will occupy one byte.  If you wanted the `2` to occupy two bytes instead, i.e. `0000 0000 0000 0010`, which is 16 bits, then you could write:

```
<<1, 2:16, 3>>
```

which the shell would display as:

```
 <<1,0,2,3>>
```

Huh?  Where did that 0 come from?  The shell displays a binary byte by byte, and the first byte of the integer `0000 0000 0000 0010` is `0000 0000`, which is 0.

Next, you can step through a binary just like you can for a list, extracting any number of bits at a time from the front of the binary.  It so happens that `split_binary/2` extracts 8 bits, or 1 byte, at a time from the head of the binary.

There are a couple of tricks to learning how to step through a binary:

1. For lists, `[]` means an empty list, and for binaries `<<>>` means an empty binary.
2. For lists you write `[Head|Tail]` to extract the head of the list, and for binaries you write `<<Bits:3, Rest/binary>>` to extract 3 bits from the front of the binary.  In your case, you need to extract 8 bits from the front of the binary.

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

split_b(Bin, N) ->
    split_b(Bin, N, _Acc = <<>>).

split_b(     Bin,               _N = 0, Acc) -> [Acc, Bin];
split_b(<<Bits:8, Rest/binary>>, N,     Acc) ->
    split_b(Rest, N-1, <<Acc/binary, Bits>>).
```

In the shell:

```
40> c(a).
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

41> a:split_b(<<5,6,7>>, 1).
[<<5>>,<<6,7>>]

42> a:split_b(<<5,6,7>>, 2).
[<<5,6>>,<<7>>]
```

Note that when constructing a binary one of the segments of the binary can be another binary:

```
23> Bin = <<1, 2, 3>>.        
<<1,2,3>>

24> Acc = <<Bin/binary, 4>>.
<<1,2,3,4>>
```

If you are actually trying to implement [lists:split/2](https://erldocs.com/21.0/stdlib/lists.html?i=0&search=lists:spli#split/2), you can do this:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

split_l(N, List) -> 
    split_l(N, List, _Acc=[]).

split_l(_N=0, List, Acc) ->
    [lists:reverse(Acc), List];
split_l(N, [H|T], Acc) -> 
    split_l(N-1, T, [H|Acc]).
```

In the shell:

```
2> c(a).
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

3> a:split_l(1, [10, 20, 30]).
["\n",[20,30]]

4> shell:strings(false).
true

5> a:split_l(1, [10, 20, 30]).
[[10],[20,30]]

6> a:split_l(2, [10, 20, 30]).
[[10,20],[30]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @7stud's answer is the best one, but I wanted to add a few minor details about your code, without actually checking if it works or not…

- `list:lenght/1` doesn't exist (unless you also created your own `list` module.

  - If you created your own `list` module, you can't use it in guards. Only BIFs are allowed there.
  - If you're trying to use `stdlib`'s function to check the length of a list, then you should use `erlang:length/1` or just `length/1`.
- It's more *idiomatic* in Erlang to use `snake_case` (e.g. `split_helper`) instead of `camelCase` (e.g. `splitHelper`) for module names, function names and atoms in general.
- You can use pattern-matching directly instead of writing an `if` as the sole expression of your function…

  ```
   split_helper([H|T], X, N, Acc) when X > N ->
     (list:reverse([H|T]), list:reverse(Acc));
   split_helper([H|T], X, N, Acc) when X<N ->
     split_helper(T, X+1, N, [H|Acc]).
  ```
- Tuples are denoted with curly braces and not parentheses: `{list:reverse([H|T]),…`. BTW… This should have prevented your code from compiling at all. The error should've looked like `syntax error before: ','`
- Also, you might have written your own `list` module, but if not and if you're trying to use `stdlib` functionality, it's `lists:reverse/1` not `list:reverse/1`.

Finally, out of that list, I would strongly recommend you to write some simple tests for your code. [This article](https://medium.com/erlang-battleground/simple-tdd-in-erlang-5c0cca886acb) may help you with that.